# Mac Chrome Multiple "top" Console Contexts on Angular Pages

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

This is a weird one I've only recently noticed since Chrome 60.0.3112.90 on Mac OS X 10.11.6, and it really impacts my daily work.

Chrome is creating a new console context every time an Angular application is reloaded, and the previous instances (presumably) stick around. This makes working in the console difficult because the context of the console sometimes remains on an old context. Whats worse is you cannot even interact with an old context so why does it remain?

I'm unsure if this is a UI bug or an actual issue with the Angular application possibly keeping reference to something from the previous context (not sure how or what would even do that).

This occurs on both the product I work on, and on the [Angular documentation website](https://docs.angularjs.org/api).

Here's a gif of it happening:
[http://i.imgur.com/lVjLJnu.gifv](https://i.imgur.com/lVjLJnu.gifv)

Every time you see me click outside of the console, I'm performing a reload.

Any ideas? This is absolutely obnoxious. I've disabled all extensions with no difference. My colleagues on Linux do not have this problem.

Comment: Uhm, actually it looks like a bug. Care to report on https://crbug.com ?

Comment: Reported: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=756442